# Adding jQuery UI with NuGet

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, nuget

I'm trying to get jQuery UI working in my Web Forms 4.5 C# project. What I've done is install it through the NuGet manager without any errors. But when adding the `ScriptReference` in my Site.Master i just get the following error:

> jquery.ui.combined is not a valid scriptname (translated from
>   Swedish).

The code I'm adding to my masterpage is

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
```

As far as I have understood it this is how I am supposed to to if I want to add jQuery UI, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the NuGet download page, search for the `AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined` package.
This will install the package and you will be able to reference it as "jquery.ui.combined"

See [this MSDN link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/nugetpackages.aspx) for a list of stable NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0):

In your master page, why don't you just reference your script using the standard script tag? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: Right now that's what I'm doing to get it to work, but since jQuery is referenced in the way mentioned above- and also a lot of other scripts- I'd like to do the same with jQuery UI.

Comment: When i download jquery ui from Nuget, file's name for combined library is jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js (for the latest version). Are you sure the name jquery.ui.combined is valid?